# Room Database issue with Type Converter Integer, Float, Long

Tags: java, android

Is it possible to use `Typeconverter` Like  `Interger`, `long`, `Double` ,`float`  in Room Database like `DateConverter`

```
public class DateTypeConverter {

    @TypeConverter
    public static Date toDate(Long value) {
        return value == null ? null : new Date(value);
    }

    @TypeConverter
    public static Long toLong(Date value) {
        return value == null ? null : value.getTime();
    }
}
```

I have tries with those `typeConverter` but it wont't work help me

Comment: it is working or not and also provide your dao class and room database class code.

Comment: Date Converter is working but when i write converter for Long it's not working ..